# Model Builder: Calculate field from Parameter defined Joined table returns 'u"String"' instead of 'String'

Tags: arcgis-pro, field-calculator, modelbuilder, unicode

Using Pro 3.2.0. The goal of this Model is to use a .xlsx spreadsheet to update values in a feature class which will be shown in a webmap. The .xlsx in question was generated from the Master Tracker (Target) initially. This all ends up in a webmap to track progress / updates. The .xlsx table will only include a small subset of the total data in the Master Tracker. ( A parcel lease tracker to be specific) .XLSX is a requirement.

I join a parameter defined table and then calculate field(s) in the target table. I use Parse Name to get the table name and then use that in my calculate field expression. Not sure if this matters but the Join table is coming from a .xlsx table. The Target and Join table have the same fields.

Master_Tracker.STATUS = '!%Name%.STATUS!'

Master Tracker is the Target Table
%Name% is the Join Table Name

The join is done based on a Common Unique Identifier. I perform an Inner join so only values that come back as a match are to be calculated.

**All of my output from this come back in the form of ' u"STATUS" ' i just want 'STATUS'**

[image: Model]

[image: Expression]

[image: Output]

Comment: So is STATUS a valid value in your field called STATUS...? In your screen shot you show "In negotiation". I understand you want to strip off u'' but the one example you give IS THE NAME of the very field itself.... So it's unclear if it is a genuine value or some error writing the field name instead.

Comment: I want the values of the field, not literally 'STATUS'. Not sure how to properly denote that. The values are being treated as Unicode and i do not understand why.

Comment: [This?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207457/convert-a-unicode-string-to-a-string-in-python-containing-extra-symbols)

Comment: Perhaps? im unsure why its even putting the output within u"" and the only thing I have found in relation to this in my searches points to u"" being a unicode tag in old python? But im not using old python? Im a bit out of my element.

Comment: This is the most relevant information i could find [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/599625/python-string-prints-as-ustring)